# How to alternate between html files and send data amongst them?

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-chrome, iframe

We have two html files, file 1 and file 2. We want to switch from file 1 to file 2 and then submit a form in file 2. We want to take the data from the form and then use it in file 1. We are trying to stick with vanilla JS/html if possible. We are switching to file 2 initially inside an event listener and then we wanted to switch back after a successful form submit

```
    window.location.replace("file2.html");
```

The redirection from file1 to file2 went through, but the redirection back to file1 from file 2 was not executing.

We also noticed that the entire function that the window.location.replace was contained within was being executed before the switch but we wanted to use the data from the form submit in file 2 within that function.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see your code within the `onSubmit()` form trigger, I guess you might not be handling the Event properly. Look into using `[Event].preventDefault();`, this will stop the form from re-rendering your file2.html before reaching the replace.

Here's [a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) for the MDN Web Docs.